# Destroy Kendo window without destrying content

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-window

I have a `div` which renders different angular JS partials.

I want to open some of those partials in a Kendo UI window and some should be displayed inline.

At first I open the partial view in a window, which works fine, but after that when I want to display a different partial inline I call the `destroy()` method on the dialog which ends up removeing the `div` which displayes the partials views.

When I do the same thing with jQuery UI dialog it doesen't remove the `div`.

Is there a way destroy the Window without removing the `div` with it.

Comment: Maybe if you reference the `div` before calling `destroy()` on the window, you can then add the `div` back into the DOM after calling destroy.

Answer (score 0):

On button click, you can displaying and hiding window.
Sample code below-

```
<button class="k-button" ng-show="!wnd2visible" ng-click="wnd2.open()">AUDIT NOTES EDITOR</button>


<div kendo-window="wnd2" k-title="'AUDIT NOTES EDITOR'" k-position="{ top: 100, left: 300 }" k-width="600" k-visible="false" k-on-open="wnd2visible = true" k-on-close="wnd2visible = false" k-modal="true">

//window content here

</div>
```

See if this helps.